# Delayed action of aurelia bindingsignaler in IE11/Edge

Tags: aurelia

Short version: Please take a look at this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdiXFOS3huYhqT3CC7i1?p=preview

I have a grid with some input fields for numeric values. If I change the editable values in one of the inputs, the row total should be updated. This works fine (= as I expect it to do) in Chrome, but not in IE11 / Edge. In the Microsoft browsers the totals will be updated on the next "blur" event, which isn't the behaviour I need.

Longer description:
My grid (app.html) (in real life this will be a form in a dialog)

```
<template>

  <require from="my-input"></require>
  <require from="my-format"></require>

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>North</td>
        <td>East</td>
        <td>West</td>
        <td>South</td>
        <td>Total</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr repeat.for="r of data.rows">
        <td>${r.year}</td>
        <td><my-input val.two-way="r.v1"></my-input></td>
        <td><my-input val.two-way="r.v2"></my-input></td>
        <td><my-input val.two-way="r.v3"></my-input></td>
        <td><my-input val.two-way="r.v4"></my-input></td>
        <td>${sumRow(r.year) & signal:'mySignal'}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</template>
```

app.js:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!';

export class App {
  data = {
    "rows": [{
      "year": "2014",
      "v1": 100,
      "v2": 200,
      "v3": 300,
      "v4": 400
    }, {
      "year": "2015",
      "v1": 500,
      "v2": 600,
      "v3": 700,
      "v4": 800
    }, {
      "year": "2016",
      "v1": 900,
      "v2": 1000,
      "v3": 1100,
      "v4": 1200
    }]
  }

sumRow(y) {
        var row = this.data.rows.find((item) => item.year === y);
        return row.v1 + row.v2 + row.v3 + row.v4;
    }
}
```

I'm using an custom input element, as all values need to be formatted into german number format, an this requires that the inputs are updated on blur.

my-input.html

```
<template>
    <require from="./my-format"></require>

    <input type="text" value.bind="val | myFormat & updateTrigger:'blur':'paste'" class="form-control" blur.trigger="myOnBlur()" />

</template>
```

To trigger the calculation of the row total after changing a value I use the Aurelia BindingSignaler:

my-input.js

```
import {bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

@inject(BindingSignaler)
export class MyInputCustomElement {
    @bindable val;

    constructor(signaler) {
        this.signaler = signaler;
    }

    myOnBlur() {
      console.log("blur");
      this.signaler.signal('mySignal');
    }

    valChanged() {
      console.log("val changed: " + this.val);
    }
}
```

My problem is that updating the row totals works perfectly in Chrome, but I need it to work in Microsoft IE11 and Edge too, and these last two browser show a different behaviour. If I change a value and move to the next input field, nothing happens, but I then move again , the update that I expected after the first move happens.

If I look at the log entrys I incorporated in the code I can see that in Chrome calls valChanged() first and then triggers blur while IE 11 does this right the other way around triggering blur first and then calling valChanged().

I tried sending the signal inside of valChanged() and although val is updated by then, the total still isn't calculated right at this point.

Am I missing something? Any suggestion how to solve this in IE11/Edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template has the following html (formatted for easier grokking):

```html
<input type="text" 
       value.bind="val | myFormat & updateTrigger:'blur':'paste'" 
       class="form-control" 
       blur.trigger="myOnBlur()">
```

The html is parsed by the browser, resulting in a DOM node that is "compiled" by Aurelia's ViewCompiler.  This compile step involves enumerating the DOM nodes [and their attributes](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/src/view-compiler.js#L338), finding all the bindings, behaviors, etc.

Given the template above, you'd expect the DOM to list the attributes in the same order they appear in the html: `type`, then `value.bind`, then `class` and finally `blur.trigger` which would ultimately result in two subscriptions to the element's `blur` event, first the `value` binding / `updateTrigger` and second the `blur.trigger`.  This is the way it works in chrome but in Internet Explorer / Edge the `blur.trigger` appears before the `value.bind` resulting in the behavior you're seeing.  Run the snippet below to see what I mean.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');
console.log('attributes: ' + Array.from(input.attributes).map(a => a.name).join(', '));
```

```html
<input type="text" 
       value.bind="val | myFormat & updateTrigger:'blur':'paste'" 
       class="form-control" 
       blur.trigger="myOnBlur()">
```

In Chrome the result will be:
[image: result]

In Edge the result will be:
[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about differences in DOM rendering, I didn't know about that.

But in my real world app, I get the 'right' order for my attributes like this:
`<input class="au-target" type="text" au-target-id="151" value.bind="z.vej2 | veFormat & updateTrigger:'blur'" blur.trigger="signaler.signal('veSignal')">`

Comment: but when you inspect the DOM element's `attributes` property you'll see that they're not in the order you'd expect when using Edge/IE.  This is what I'm attempting to demonstrate in my answer.  You cannot rely on the order that the DOM events will be subscribed.  You'll need to add some sort of delay to your `blur.trigger` handler to ensure it doesn't process the total until after the `updateTrigger` has done it's thing.

Comment: Ok, now I understood. I was able to delay the calculation of the totals to get the behavior I wanted. But in the end I decided to go with a different solution that uses the aurelia property observer.

Comment: nice- glad that makes sense.  Please mark this question as answered (the little checkmark)